# Campanolo record power meter crank with veloce crankset

Tags: crankset, power, campagnolo

Can I use a Stages Campagnolo Record left crank with my Campagnolo veloce crankset,   if the sizes are a match?

Want a power meter of some sorts and it would be far cheaper than getting vectors.

Comment: What about a one-sided Vector? You can still upgrade later and transfer between bikes. The Stages website specifies that the Chorus (!) version is compatible with Chorus and Record-11s. https://www.stagescycling.eu/stages-power/campagnolo-chorus.html

Comment: Powertap P2s are another option.  Too bad you weren't looking a few months ago - Powertap was dumping their C1 crankset powermeters *cheap* after they got bought out by SRAM.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The C1 is technically a chainring powermeter rather than crankset.  And if they are dumping stock that would make me worry about availability of replacement chainrings in the future

Comment: @AndyP All true, but they were dumping them for $350, which seems to be about the same as SRM charges me to replace the battery and service my SRM crankset every 4-5 years.  I love that SRM (except that's it's FSA-based) and want a new one, but not for $2500. The bad reviews on the C1 were almost all leaking battery seal and short battery life and most likely user problems - not seating the seal after replacing the battery and using cheap years-old CR2032s off the internet. Add in the cost of a decent crankset, and the C1 was L/R power for just $400+. (L/R power is a pretty decent estimate)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

The Veloce crankset (assuming it's a 2011+ version) uses Campy's [Power Torque](https://www.campagnolo.com/US/en/Technologies/power_torque_system) system to attach the left crank arm.

The [Centaur crankarm offered by Stages](https://www.campagnolo.com/US/en/Components/chorus_crankset_old) uses [Campy's Ultra Torque](https://www.campagnolo.com/US/en/Technologies/ultra_torque) design, as do [all of the Campy crankarms Stages offers](https://www.stagescycling.eu/stages-power/campagnolo/).

They are completely different.